# make a kendo cell readonly based on dropdownselection in the grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid that has a dropdownlist in one of the columns. Based on the dropdownlist selection, I want to be able to disable or enable the other columns. How can i achieve this? I tried some examples but I couldn't get anywhere with it. The dropdownlist in the grid has three options - Internal, External and both. On selecting Internal i want the Column with Internal Amount to be enabled, similarly for other options. Every cell has a dropdownlist and based on the selection I want the other internal amount cell and external amount disabled and enabled based on the option selected from the DDL.

Code:

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.StaggingInternal)
        .Name("StaggingGridTest")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.RowID).Title("StaggingRowID").Width(130).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.EnterText1).Title("Description").Width(130) ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.Dateoftransaction).Title("Date").Width(130).Format("{0:d}").Width(130); 
            columns.ForeignKey(p => p.ExceptionsCategoryID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"], "ExceptionsCategoryID", "ExceptionsCategory")
               .Title("Category").Width(130);
            columns.Bound(p => p.InternalLocalAmount).Title("InternalAmt").Width(130);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ExternalLocalAmount).Title("ExternalAmt").Width(130);

            //columns.Command(command => command.destroy()).Width(130);

        })
              .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                    {

                        toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "customCommand" }); // The "create" command adds new data items.
                        toolbar.Save().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "saveCommand" });// The "save" command saves the changed data items.

                    })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) // Use in-cell editing mode.
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })



        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Input(true)
        .Numeric(false)
        )
               .Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
                 .Sortable()
                 .ColumnMenu()
                 .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
                 .Filterable()
                  .Navigatable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()

        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)


                     .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates.
                               .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.RowID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model.
                                        model.Field(p => p.RowID).Editable(false); 
                                        model.Field(p => p.ExceptionsCategoryID).DefaultValue(1);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Category).Editable(true);

                                    })



                  .Update("Editing_Update", "MultiTab")
                  .Create("Editing_Create", "MultiTab")

                   )

        )
//.Events(e=>e.onEdit) //gives a side effect, when I include this and click on Add new row, instead of adding a new row in the grid, it opens the grid in a new page. It's a weird side effect i think.

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var gridOutput = $("#StaggingCashExceptionsGridTest").data("kendoGrid");

        //gridOutput.bind("beforeEdit", onEdit.bind(gridOutput));

        function onEdit(e) {
            e.container.find("input[name='Name']").each(function () { $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled") }); // this doesn't work, was just trying something based on the link that i found
        }
</script>
```

Any ideas will be very helpful. I'm attaching a picture of the grid, to show what exactly i want. [image]

Category is the dropdownlist, when i select on internal, external amount should not be editable and only internal amount should be editable. That should be done for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but there are a few things you need to fix.

Firstly, it looks like you have assigned the edit event handler wrong. Uncomment it and change it to this:

```
.Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
```

Move the event handler so that it is **before the grid widget** declaration and also outside of the document `ready` event. Change it to this:

```
<script>

            function onEdit(e) {
                    // Check to see if the current value of Category is 'On Internal'
                    if(e.model.Category=="On Internal"){
                        // Disable the ExternalAmt text box
                        e.container.find("input[name='ExternalAmt']").each(function ()
                          {
                             $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled") });
                          }
                    }

                   // Check to see if the current value of Category is 'On External'
                    if(e.model.Category=="On External"){
                        // Disable the InternalAmt text box
                        e.container.find("input[name='InternalAmt']").each(function ()
                          {
                             $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled") });
                          }
                    }

            }

<script>
```

And that should work, provided that 'Category', 'ExternalAmt', and 'InternalAmt' are the right field names in your model.

Comment: thanks for the snippet. In fact i changed the event handler before, I realized that what's there was wrong and i changed it to .Event(ev=>ev.Edit('onEdit')) and i just put an alert to check if it's working on it. So the issue that i have is whenever i click on Add button at the top of the grid, it opens the grid in another page. I don't know if it's a side effect. Is there a specific place to place the events method in the grid?

Comment: You mean it opens a new browser tab?

Comment: Also, my model would be var model=$("#StaggingGridTest").data("kendoGrid") and category is the title, exceptionscategoryID is the field. so, i should be comparing with exceptionscategoryID right?

Comment: :Yes, it navigates to another page and shows the grid. Basically I'm loading the grid as a partial view in a page. So when I click on add, it opens the grid in another page. When i remove events method, it adds a row in the grid like how it's supposed to.

Comment: Yes, compare e.model.exceptionscategoryID to whatever the value is supposed to be. As far as opening a new page - are there any errors in the console? When you tried the alert in the onEdit function - did it work?

Comment: The alert didn't work, it doesn't even trigger that function and the error that i get is kendo.all.min.js:54 ReferenceError: onEdit is not defined, which is weird because I declared onEdit in the script. maybe i thought that it's looking before the script is loaded so i included script at the top of the page.

Comment: OK, you need to move the entire <script></script> block so that it appears BEFORE the @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.StaggingInternal)... line. And you also need to take the function onEdit(e) { ... } function OUTSIDE of the  $(document).ready(...) function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @orliux: Awesome, that worked. But why should it be outside the document,ready function, i thought document,ready is when the script should be triggered once all the DOM elements are constructed?

Comment: Because @(Html.Kendo().Grid()) renders the grid widget before document .ready is triggered. That meant that the onEdit function was not available when the grid was rendered and it failed to bind it to the event.